# DjangoRestFramework quiero el nombre no el id

Tags: django, djangorestframework

Tengo una relación en un modelo, quiero que me muestres el nombre que tiene asignado y no el ID

de apps.control.models Tengo:

```
class Movimiento(models.Model):
    tipo = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, null=True, choices=TIPO)# Compra o Nacimiento
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True, choices=DESCRIP)# Tipo de animal. Semental, Engorda, Vientre, Reemplazo, Producto
    fecha = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    arete = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    pesonacimiento = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    raza = models.ForeignKey(Raza, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='movimiento_raza')
    imagen = models.ImageField(verbose_name="Imagen", blank=True, null=True, upload_to="ovinos")
    peso = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    observaciones = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.arete
```

de apps.catalogos.models Tengo:

```
class Raza(models.Model):
    codigo = models.CharField(max_length=4,blank=True,null=True)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)
    color = ColorField(default='#FF0000')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre
```

mi serializer es:

```
class MovimientoSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    descripcion = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    tipo = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Movimiento
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_descripcion(self,obj):
        dato = obj.get_descripcion_display()
        return dato

    def get_tipo(self,obj):
        dato = obj.get_tipo_display()
        return dato
```

¿Qué puedo hacer para obtener el nombre del catálogo de la raza y no la id? ¿Puede alguien ayudarme por favor?

Comment: Podrías usar algún plugin como [drf-flex-fields](https://github.com/rsinger86/drf-flex-fields) o simplemente dentro del `MovimientoSerializer` definir otro campo a parte de `tipo` y `descripcion` que se llame `raza` y debe ser igual al serializer que crees para la clase `Raza`, lo que pasa es que al momento de guardar te costará bastante si no conoces bien el código de `rest-framework`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Gracias ya pude hacerlo

```
class MovimientoSerializer(ModelSerializer):
raza = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field="nombre", queryset=Raza.objects.all())
```

Tomando los ejemplos de la siguiente liga da los ejemplos de la relaciones y como solo obtengo el id, realiza la consulta para traer el nombre de ese id. Gracias

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/

**Otra forma**
Como ya tengo serializado mis modelos, lo mando a importar y lo presento:

```
class MovimientoSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    descripcion = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    tipo = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)    
    raza = RazaSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Movimiento
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_descripcion(self,obj):
        dato = obj.get_descripcion_display()
        return dato

    def get_tipo(self,obj):
        dato = obj.get_tipo_display()
        return dato
```

Comment: El sistema detecto esta publicacion como de baja calidad. Podrias agregar algo de contexto a la respuesta? (porque resuelve el problema, documentacion de esa funcion o algo).

Answer (score 1):

Por si te sirve está otra opción

```
class MovimientoSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    descripcion = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    tipo = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    nombre_raza = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Movimiento
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_descripcion(self,obj):
        dato = obj.get_descripcion_display()
        return dato

    def get_tipo(self,obj):
        dato = obj.get_tipo_display()
        return dato

     def get_nombre_raza(self, obj): 
         return obj.raza.nombre
```

Comment: Gracias encontré otra forma también edito mi respuesta anterior